# No me detecta el responsive en mobile first

Tags: css

No me detecta el responsive en mobile first. ¿Cuál puede ser la falla? Porque en escritorio sí me aparece todo correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas fácil.
Pongo aquí el link de mi repositorio de github donde lo subí.
Hasta ahora no funciona con lo que han propuesto y ya llevo 2días y 9hrs perdidas =(, pero agradezco sus aportaciones.
https://github.com/rych182/gdl

Gracias por tomarse la molestia de ayudarme, gracias de antemano

Comment: Como te comenta @blonfu, añade el código como texto, indicando las partes que afectan a tu problema. Por otra parte, cuando hay problemas de CSS que no se muestran o que tienen comportamientos inesperados, siempre puedes utilizar las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador o Firebug para ver que estilos están afectando a tus etiquetas, suele darse el caso que entra en conflicto con otra o que no esta definida correctamente y por eso no se está aplicando.

Comment: Usaste la etiqueta viewport?

Comment: En la captura de pantalla se ve que el protocolo es `file://` (en lugar de ver la página desde el servidor web, estás abriéndola desde como local). Si el código apunta al CSS del servidor, puede que no se esté cargando y verías el error que estás viendo (que parece que no se carga ningún estilo). Abre la consola del desarrollador y mira los errores, porque seguro hay un 404 en main.css.

Comment: Te falta un cierre de llave en tu `main.css`. En la línea 404 tienes una `mediaquery` para tablet que no cierras bien.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que estés bien, te compartiré el código completo de mi index.html sólo le agregué la estructura básica para HTML, según veo en las imágenes que añadiste, no has vinculado tu hoja de estilos al HTML, y creo que te falta la etiqueta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` que te permite indicar cómo se verá un proyecto web en dispositivo haciendo una escala del width. El CSS lo puse exactamente como lo tienes tú, no le cambié nada.

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your page title here :)</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="contador parallax">
    <div class="contenedor">
        <ul class="resumen-evento clearfix">
            <li><p class="numero">6</p> Invitados</li>
            <li><p class="numero">15</p> Talleres</li>
            <li><p class="numero">3</p> Días</li>
            <li><p class="numero">9</p> Conferencias</li>
         /ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> RESULTADO
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva mi ayuda.